# preg_replace words not inside a url

Tags: regex, url, preg-replace, assertion

I am using preg_replace to replace a list of words in a text that may contain some urls.
The problem is that I don't want to replace these words if they're part of a url.

These examples should be ignored:

> foo.com
>
> foo.com/foo
>
> foo.com/foo/foo

For a basic example (written in php), I tried to ignore strings containing **.com** and optional slashes and chars, using a negative look ahead assertion, but with no success:

`preg_replace("/(\b)foo(\b)/", "$1bar$2(?!(\w+\.\w+)*(\.com)([\.\/]\w+)*)", $text);`

This call works just ignores the word before **.com**.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases  like these, its much easier to think of the problem inverted. You want to match words *not* in an url. Instead think, you want to match the url *and* the words. So, your expression would look like this: `url_match_here|(?:my|words|here)`. This will allow the regex engine to consume the URL first and then try to match those words. Thus, you never have to worry about matching the words inside an URL. If you want to maintain the text structure, you can use `preg_replace`, with the following expression `(url_match_here)|(?:my|words|here)` and replace by `\1` to preserve the URL and the text.

I hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to achieve that.
How can a make the replacement only when the second opction matches?
for example **foo foo.com** should produce **bar foo.com**
but your solution will produce **bar foo.com bar**

Comment: Finally I was able to solve the problem using your approach, but I was only able to consume the discarded part of the string using a preg_replace_callback function and inside the callback decide if I was processing or no the matched string.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I had completely missed your comment, sorry.