# Regex negative on string

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

How can I get the negative of the result of this regex?

```
8000[0-9]{12}|4000[0-9]{12}|2000[0-9]{11}
```

I just want to modify the regex to get the negative.

Example with this sample:

```
200045646587982  
8000046678465132  
8000078526654112  
4000846464256741  
4000875465123111  
8318548479844423  
8020489065458054
```

If I execute the current regex, I get that result:

```
200045646587982  
8000046678465132  
8000078526654112  
4000846464256741  
4000875465123111
```

I want the regex returns the reverse:

```
8318548479844423  
8020489065458054
```

Comment: By negative do you mean inverse?

Comment: So you want to match, when this pattern doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what tools you can use.

I would take my input and use the "positive" regexp to replace the matching lines with empty strings and then getting rid of them.

For instance, if your input is a file and you are working in an Unix environment:

cat input.txt | sed s/my-positive-regexp//g

would replace the matching strings with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

View my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12139118/1548853

Even though the answer is not directed towards you entirely, the same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simpler than inverting / negating the pattern.

```
    if (!Regex.IsMatch("input", "pattern")) 
    {
    }
```

Comment: I know how to do that in c# and it is easy but I need to modify the regex expression to get the reverse of my current result.

Comment: No you don't "need to".  You could just read the data line by line.